# Sideload a plugin in Microsoft Office 365 on desktop

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I want to learn something about plugin development for Office (or to be specific) Outlook 365 on my Desktop.

So I started reading documentation and tutorials.
Among that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing to get started with a simple plugin. Unfortunately, the aforementioned document is not valid for the current (Oct 2018) Outlook 365 on Desktops - only for older versions.

Can anybody explain, how to sideload a plugin with the latest Office 365?

Comment: Have you checked this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins. The official website does not provide the latest version of the Outlook add-in test.

Comment: Okay - that seems promising - I'll try it during the Weekend. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: For development, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/ .

Comment: Are you trying to sideload on Outlook for Windows, Outlook on the Web or Outlook for Mac?

Comment: You should see a GetAddins button in the ribbon for desktop and for Web you can find it in the drop down where reply/forward options are present on the each message at the top right corner. We will update our documentation soon to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry, I did not have the time to dig into this until now.  
I try to sideload an outlook plug-in. I see the button, but I have no clue how to go on after that.  
The current documentation seems only to be usable with word/excel/pp

Comment: To make it even more complicated, my outlook account is a workplace joined account and adding an add-in tries to connect to the on-premise owa.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? how?

Comment: @Bruce that is only for Word. *How to sideload addins for Outlook 365 on desktop*?

Comment: Nah - sorry - the plan for my plugin is still on my table and not acted upon (side project)